# Problem while trying to export iTunes library to an xml file (on OS X 10.8, iTunes 11.1.3)

Tags: itunes, macos, partition, migration

Short version: When I try to export iTunes library to an xml file, iTunes creates a temporary file (called iTunes export.tmp) and it quickly disappears and I don't get any xml file...

Long version: I have partitioned my HD and made a clean Mavericks install on the second partition. In order to migrate my iTunes library, I've moved the media files to an external HD ('cause the second partition is too small to contain them) and iTunes keeps working fine on Mountain Lion. Now I'm trying to export my library from Mountain Lion and import on Mavericks. When I finish the tests with Mavericks, I'll probably keep it and drop Mountain Lion (if all the apps I use work fine on Mavericks, I'm testing now). It would be really great if I could keep all the metadata on my iTunes library after the migration...

Is there any other way to migrate my iTunes library? or maybe something I could do to fix this issue with the xml export?

Comment: How do you export this file - iTunes has an xml file automatically

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve the main reason I was asking this question... (Although I couldn't make Export Library work from iTunes on my Mountain Lion partition)

I booted into Mavericks and then I copied the iTunes folder from Mountain Lion partition to the Mavericks one and it worked as expected... :-)

My library is migrated, including play counts, playlists, album arts, ratings... Well, it's all there.

Note: The iTunes is up to date on both partitions (version 11.1.3).

Note 2: In order to migrate my iOS devices' backups, I also copied from Mountain Lion to Mavericks the folder ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync.

I'm still curious why export library was not working, but my problem is gone.